# How to keep "+" in URL?

Tags: url, whatsapp

I want to create link for Whatsapp message which contain web URL with "+" on it.
Message will be something like this:

> Hello GREGORY please visit this link:<new_line>https://winvitation.id/premium-8/?to=GREGORY+from+TIMBUKTU&app_absent=1&lang=id

But when I put it to Whatsapp "API" message like below:

> https://wa.me/0000000?text=Hello%20GREGORY%20please%20visit%20this%20link:%0ahttps://winvitation.id/premium-8/?to=GREGORY+from+TIMBUKTU&app_absent=1&lang=id

When it got in to Whatsapp it will looks like this:

[image: Preview result in Whatsapp]

See that the "+" in URL is replaced with "space" and the link is not working as intended anymore.

How do I keep the "+" in URL?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just found it!

Simply replace the "+" with "%2B"....